# VCLZip: Ask if readonly files should be overwritten

Tags: delphi, zip, delphi-2007, unzip, vclzip

I'm using VCLZip 2.21 to unzip a zip file. I can make TVCLUnzip overwrite readonly files by setting ReplaceReadOnly to True. But how do I implement a confirmation by the user? I already added an OnSkippingFile handler setting Retry to True but this doesn't result in an additional try. (AFAICT the Retry variable is never read.) Do you have any advice?

Comment: BTW: Does anybody still use VCLZip? The [forum](http://vclzip.proboards.com/index.cgi) seems dead.

Comment: No, we switched to Abbrevia Zip some time ago. Main Reason for us, its not dead and works with 64-Bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you shouldn't change `ReplaceReadOnly`. Instead, set [`OverwriteMode`](http://vclzip.bizland.com/help/hs2545.htm) to `Prompt`, and then handle the [`OnPromptForOverwrite`](http://vclzip.bizland.com/help/hs2515.htm) event. In that event, check whether the file is read-only, and only prompt if it is.

Otherwise, you could *try* changing the read-only flag of a file in the `OnSkippingFile` event handler before setting `Retry`, but [the documentation](http://vclzip.bizland.com/help/hs2520.htm) doesn't say the `Retry` parameter is used in that situation. It only talks about retrying during *zipping* operations where it couldn't open the to-be-zipped file, not during *unzipping* operations.

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation for `OnSkippingFile` isn't up to date - e.g. it doesn't even mention `srCreateError` which is the `Reason` I get in the discussed situation.